# ios 6: prompt user to log into facebook

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using UIActivityViewController to use facebook integration within my app.  I've observed that in order for the Facebook option to be displayed in the list of displayed options, the user needs to be logged into Facebook on their device in the settings prior to entering that UIActivityViewController.

I'd like to prompt the user to log into Facebook and allow my app access to their account prior to invoking the UIActivityViewController.  Is there a way to prompt the user to log into Facebook on their device (I guess I'm looking for a redirect or hook to the Settings app, with a callback)?

Note: I'd like to avoid using the Facebook SDK, and use the purely Apple supplied framework.

Comment: check out: http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/tutorial-how-to-use-inbuilt.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with `UIActivityViewController`.

But you can achieve same function via `SLComposeViewController`.

I created a forked project [OWActivityViewController](https://github.com/brantyoung/OWActivityViewController) that implement the same function as Apple's built-in **Photos** app's share action sheet through `SLComposeViewController`.

[OWActivityViewController](https://github.com/brantyoung/OWActivityViewController) use the purely Apple supplied framework, compatible with iOS 5, hope this could help you somehow.